# multiple location blocks in nginx and proxy pass

Tags: nginx, server, reverse-proxy, prometheus, grafana

I am trying to run 2 applications behind an NGINX server.

one is listening on 3000 (grafana) and one is listening on 9090 (prometheus)

My current server block nginx.conf looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }

location /prometheus{
   proxy_pass http://localhost:9090/;
  }

}
```

Now for Grafana, this works perfectly and everything works in the dashboard.
But when typing Domain/prometheus it still redirects me to grafana instead of Prometheus.

Do I need todo something specific to have it working in this setup that everything besides /prometheus is redirected to grafana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it now by doing this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;
    
location /prometheus {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:9090/prometheus;
  }

   
location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, `http://localhost:9090` will be redirected to `http://localhost:9090/graph`, so the request is being redirected as below:

```
# the origin request
http://Domain/prometheus

# the request redirect by nginx
http://localhost:9090/

# the request redirect by prometheus
http://Domain/graph

# the request redirect by nginx again
http://localhost:3000/graph
```

You can check this by using F12 in Chrome. 
To fix this, I recommend you separate the domain into two domains:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name Domain-Grafana; # Domain for Grafana
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
  }
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name Domain-Prometheus; # Domain for Prometheus
  root /usr/share/nginx/html;
  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
   proxy_pass http://localhost:9090/;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you for this solution, This would indeed work but I want to be able to use the same domain. Its also a bit of a question on how I can manage this kind of setup for learning nginx logic :)